# Manipulating ref'd mongo records based on _id field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, nosql

Ok so I have a pretty simple DB setup in a MEAN app (node, mongoose, mongo) where I have Book records, and User records. A book has a single Owner, and can have any number of shared users which are stored in an array in a field called sharedWith:.  Originally I was storing the user records with an email address as the _id field. I now realize this was a dumb move on my part because if someone wants to change their email address it effectively cuts them off from their books.

The app is not live yet, so it's not a fatal mistake.

My question is, once I revert the User documents to using the original hash value for _id, and  store those in the Owner and sharedWith fields in the book documents, will I have to query each hash just to retrieve the actual usable user data?

I know mongoose has a .populate() method which will resolve sub documents, but as for inserting them? Will I POST the users as email addresses, then query each and store the resulting hashes? I can do this manually, but I wanted to make sure there is not some secret mongo-sauce that can do this in the DB itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `_id` available in the frontend for the `user`. You can directly share him a book by adding the `_id` to the `sharedWith` array of a book. But if you don't have the `_id` of the user available in the frontend, you need to manually get the `_id` by querying with  the `email` and then store the `_id` in the `sharedWith`. As to retrieve the books, `populate` is indeed the best option to use to get user data.

And to get all books shared with a `user` you can do something like this,

```
Book.find({sharedWith:user1._id},function(err,docs){ });
```

This query can be made efficient if you use an `index` on `sharedWith` but that depends on your use case.

Comment: Cool that's what I was thinking, thanks for reaffirming that I was on the right track. I need to read more about indexing too as I'm not really sure how to do that and what the improvement is.

I will need to query though as users will be added by raw email address. Thanks!